# My Code Is Broken (I'm a Newbie) UnboundLocalError: local variable 'wood' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

**THIS IS MY CODE, and it for some reason is broken. Log:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 134, in <module>
  File "python", line 123, in usernat
  File "python", line 74, in play
  File "python", line 85, in play2
  File "python", line 101, in play3
  File "python", line 114, in play4
  File "python", line 18, in play5
  File "python", line 21, in play6
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'wood' referenced before assignment
```

-- **CODE** --

```
global farms
global wood
global clay
global resourcecol
wood=10
clay=10

def usernat():
    rome='Rome'
    usernation=input("Enter your nation: ")
    def play5():

            wood=0
            clay=0
            print("(Your wood and clay has been stolen by the local barbarians)")
            print("Now we would want to get some resources, just so we could be safe from a crisis, when our farms will be destroyed.")
            print("Let's collect resources, type wood or clay to send your men to collect the resources")
            play6()
    def play6():
            resourcecol=input("Collect Wood/Clay or cancel? ")
            if wood>100:
                print("Your wood storages are full")
                play6()
            elif clay>100:
                print("Your clay storages are full")
                play6()
            elif resourcecol=="wood":
                wood=wood+10
                print("Your men have successfully got ",wood, " wood.")
                play6()

            elif resourcecol=="clay":
                clay=clay+10
                print("Your men have successfully got ", clay, " clay.")
                play6()
            elif resourcecol=="cancel":
                play7()
            elif resourcecol=="Cancel":
                play7()
            elif resourcecol=="CANCEL":
                play7()
            elif resourcecol=="Clay":
                clay=clay+10
                print("Your men have successfully got ", clay, " clay.")
                play6()
            elif resourcecol=="CLAY":
                clay=clay+10
                print("Your men have successfully got ", clay, " clay.")
                play6()
            elif resourcecol=="Wood":
                wood=wood+10
                print("Your men have successfully got ",wood, " wood.")
                play6()
            elif resourcecol=="WOOD":
                wood=wood+10
                print("Your men have successfully got ",wood, " wood.")
                play6()
            else:
                print("Command does not exist, please check spelling errors.")
                play6()


    def play7():
        print("Play7 activated")
    def play():
            print("You have chosen to play as: ", usernation)
            global troops
            global gold
            troops=0
            gold=200
            print("You currently have ", troops, "troops")
            print("You currently have ", gold, "gold")
            print("Since your nation needs immediate security, recruit at least '50' troops")
            play2()
    def play2():
            troops=int(input("Recruit Troops: "))
            global endgold
            endgold=gold-2*troops
            if endgold>=0:
                if troops<50:
                    print("Your nation will not be secure with less than 50 troops, please recruit 50 or more.")
                    troops=0
                    play2()
                print("You currently have ", troops, "troops and ", endgold, "Gold")
                play3()
            else:
                print("You cannot recruit more troops than your funds can afford")
                troops=0
                play2()
    def play3():
        global wheat
        wood=10
        wheat=10
        clay=10
        farms=0
        global farm_cons
        farm_cons=clay+wood
        print("You need more gold! Build some farms.")
        print("You currently have avaiable resources for ", farm_cons/4, " farms.")
        print("Build as many as you want from the avaiable.")
        play4()
    def play4():
        farms=int(input("Build Farms: "))
        global availablefarms
        availablefarms=clay+wood/4
        if farms<=availablefarms:
            if farms<1:
                print("You cannot build less than 1 farm")
                play4()
                if farms>availablefarms:
                    print("Your resources cannot afford to build ", farms, " farms")
                    play4()
            print(farms, " farms are under construction.")
            play5()
        else:
            print("Insufficient amount of farms")
            play4()


    if usernation=='Rome' :
            play()
    elif usernation=='rome' :
            play()
    elif usernation=='ROME' :
            play()
    else :
        print("That nation does not exist")

    return


print("Nations:")
print("Rome [Caesar]")
usernat();
print ("Values outside the function: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Those globals (wood, clay, resourcecol) need to be declared global in every function that uses them.  That's true in Python 3, at least, which is what you appear to be using.

One thing you should consider is redesigning how you are moving from one part of the game to another.  As far as I can tell, right now you get there by a direct call that doesn't return until the program ends.

Each call stores the previous functions context on a stack, and that stack will eventually fill up.

Answer (score 0):

So, like @Mike is pointing, your trying to do something good in a less than good way. One approach is to redefine your resources to a dictionary that everything gets access to. The following toy code should, hopefully, give you enough of a start to redesign your approach. Keep going!

```
# You can access your dictionary anywhere
def play1():
    print game_dict['wood']


def play2():
    if game_dict['clay'] < 100:
        print "You need some clay!"
    game_dict['wood'] += 2
    print "Now you have %d wood" % game_dict['wood']

# create a constructor for your game data, I called it game_dict, but
# there is nothing special about this name. Set various properties 
# here that you can then modify in other functions 
def initialize_game_dict(initial_wood, initial_clay):
    local_dict = {'wood': ""}
    local_dict = {'clay': ""}
    local_dict['wood'] = initial_wood
    local_dict['clay'] = initial_clay
    return(local_dict)


game_dict = initialize_game_dict(10,25)


print "You are starting now with %d wood and %d clay" % (game_dict['wood'], game_dict['clay'])

play1()
play2()def play1():
    print game_obj.wood
```